# Game request sent on facebook succeed，but friend did not get the request

Tags: ios, facebook

In iOS code i have sent game request to my friend but he did not getting the request in his facebook account.
this code I added for game inviting to friend

```
FBSDKGameRequestContent *gameRequestContent = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc] init];

gameRequestContent.message = @"game name"; 
gameRequestContent.title = @"title";

// Assuming self implements <FBSDKGameRequestDialogDelegate>
FBSDKGameRequestDialog *Request = [FBSDKGameRequestDialog alloc]init];
Request.content = gameRequestContent;
Request.delegate = delegate;
[Request show];
```

I have received didCompletwithResults deleagte Callback : Request ID and friend FBID

Indicates that the invitation has been successful ! ! !

But my friend not getting the request.emmmm

Comment: Did they look at https://www.facebook.com/games/activity ?

Comment: Yes, I checked, but I haven't

Comment: Did you friend check?

Comment: I have two facebook account

Comment: You are only allowed to have one.

Comment: One of my own accounts, a friend lent me

Comment: Which is not allowed by Facebook Terms of Service.

Comment: Okay, I'm just doing the test function